# Best way to tell if an SMTP message has an IMF header?

Tags: c#, smtp

I am writing an SMTP parser that needs to handle standard smtp as well as SMTP messages sent from a system that I do not control, which do not include an IMF header. For example,

Standard SMTP with IMF header:

```
From: "Blah blah blah" blah@bluhblah.blah
To: Derp@dederp.com
Subject: This is a standard SMTP message
Date: Mon, 5 Oct 2009 11:36:07 +0530
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text / plain
Content-Language: en-us
Testing testing 1 2 3
```

Bastardized SMTP:

```
Testing testing 1 2 3
```

Preferably in C#, but any language is fine.
<strike>No speculation please, I need someone who understands the SMTP / IMF specs to respond.</strike> I take that back, speculate all you want. lol

Comment: write a regex and compare each msg against it (regex has special character "^" which matches only from the beginning of a header)

Comment: So, the bad case means the sender only includes the basic message but no message headers?  What does IMF stand for for you?  Because that's not an acronym I'm familiar with in the context of SMTP mail.

Comment: IMF is internet message format. It's all the From: To: crap at the beginning of the data push during an SMTP conversation. RFC 2822. The issue I'm having is distinguishing whether or not the data is a header or user entered text. Just about all the fields for an IMF header are optional and can be in any order.

Comment: IMF can be found here:  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you really, really want to write your own SMTP parser; you'll want a 3rd party library to help. We chose [OpenPop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/). It works well, handles all the things we've thrown at it, and is still supported.

No, I'm not affiliated with them.

Comment: I decided to go with OpenPOP. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

couple of things.

You don't want a SMTP parser, you want a Mime message parser. Parsing mime messages is not a trivial exercise. There are 1000s of broken message formats out there, or just plain weird formats, yet still RFC2822 (Mime Message) compliant.

I recommend just using a Mime message parser (either one from codeproject or like source -- if you want a free one), or else a commercial prouduct.

Then, just loop through the headers to see if they match your rules.

--Dave
PS: I'm partial to aspNetMime, since I wrote it.

Comment: Well, I'm writing an SMTP, IMF, MIME parser. But I believe IMF is what the header section is called, and MIME extends IMF for attachments. Correct me if I'm wrong, I've only been reading the RFC's for a couple days now. You are correct though, I've decided to go with OpenPOP, MIME is a pain in the @ss.

Comment: SMTP defines an email envelope; IMF and MIME define the contents.  IMF is for plain text; MIME is for everything else.